# Want to calculate the end date from the start date given using CjuiDatePicker

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to yii framework and i am using the `CJUIDatePicker` to get a start_date which is inserted to my table. I also have a field called end_date and I want to insert the end_date from the code, e.g. like this:

```
$this->end_date = $this->start_date + 2Months; // how to do this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it after some more research .Here it is

$currentDate = $this->start_date;//sets the start_date to the variable

$this->end_date= date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+4 year',strtotime($currentDate)));//the end_date is now start_date plus 4 years

thank

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.3 you could also check out the new Date functions and do something like `$end_date = new DateTime($this->start_date);
$this->end_date = $end_date->add(new DateInterval('P4Y'))->format('Y-m-d');`. Also note that the DatePicker js provides some nice date functions if you want to do any date manipulation in js.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the format for `start_date` and `end_date`. If it's a UNIX timestamp, then the simplest would be:

```
$this->end_date = strtotime('+2 months', $this->start_date);
```

If it's something else, the answer depends on what exactly.

Comment: yea thnx @Jon ,i actually gat it to work.but its the same as yours..thnx alot